# skip bad record in redshift data load

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data into AWS redshift using following command

```
copy venue from 's3://mybucket/venue'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>'
delimiter '\t';
```

but data load is failing, when I checked Query section for that specific load I noticed it failed because of "Bad UTF8 hex sequence: a4 (error 3)"

Is there a way to skip bad records in data load into redshift?

Comment: Got it MAXERROR   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, you can use the maxerror parameter.  This example will allow up to 250 bad records to be skipped (the errors are written to stl_load_errors):

```
copy venue 
from 's3://mybucket/venue' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=' 
delimiter '\t' 
maxerror as 250;
```